# Apache Flink batch mode

Tags: apache-flink

My Flink applications configured to run in batch mode. It runs fine in local environment as expected in blocking shuffle pattern. Blocking shuffle not working in cluster environment. All operators started and processing in a stream mode… those operators that completed processing turned to finished state. I want pipeline should run in blocking shuffle mode … i.e. next dependent operator should not start until previous operator finished processing.

Can anyone come across this behavior? Again it is happening only in cluster environment.

Thanks